# VBA Hyperlink.Add to another cell in the same Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I want to create a hyperlink for each takeaway entered on the sheet, and have all of the hyperlinks placed in a dynamic range below where the takeaways are entered.

A loop calls on the following code where "pkey" is the name of the worksheet that will contain the trigger detected by the macro (that creates the hyperlink 1 by 1):

```
Public Sub Takeaways(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal table As Range, ByVal pkey As String)

Dim Lastcolumn As Long
Dim takeawaylastrow As Long
Dim takeawayfirstrow As Range
Dim takeawaypasterange As Range
Dim takeaway_description As String

Lastcolumn = ws.Cells(table.row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
takeaway_description = ws.Cells(table.row, Lastcolumn)
Set takeawayfirstrow = ws.Range("Takeaways").Offset(0, 1)
takeawaylastrow = ws.Range("Takeaways").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).row
Set takeawaypasterange = ws.Cells(takeawaylastrow + 1, New_Meeting_Task_Columns.Trigger)

takeawaypasterange = takeaway_description

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(pkey).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(pkey) & "!" & Cells.takeawaypasterange.Address, Address:="", SubAddress:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(pkey).table(1, 1).Address, TextToDisplay:="Takeaway"

End sub
```

The last line of code produces the error "438, Object doesn't support this property or method", I've tried hard-coding instead of using named ranges/variables, and spent time looking at other Hyperlinks.Add examples when changing the format of my error line, but I cannot get the code to run.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing of `Cells.takeawaypasterange.Address` with only `takeawaypasterange.Address`...

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work (dim temp as string, and in the hyperlinks formula, anchor:= takeawaypasterange and subaddress:=temp did the trick)

```
Public Sub Takeaways(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal table As Range, ByVal pkey As String)

Dim Lastcolumn As Long
Dim takeawaylastrow As Long
Dim takeawayfirstrow As Range
Dim takeawaypasterange As Range
Dim takeaway_description As String

dim temp as string

Lastcolumn = ws.Cells(table.row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
takeaway_description = ws.Cells(table.row, Lastcolumn)
Set takeawayfirstrow = ws.Range("Takeaways").Offset(0, 1)
takeawaylastrow = ws.Range("Takeaways").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).row
Set takeawaypasterange = ws.Cells(takeawaylastrow + 1, New_Meeting_Task_Columns.Trigger)

takeawaypasterange = takeaway_description
temp = table(1, 1).Address

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(pkey).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=takeawaypasterange, _
Address:="", SubAddress:=temp, TextToDisplay:="testttttt"

End sub
```